# How to create pull request for wiki of a repository on Bitbucket?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I forked a repository, also separately forked its wiki, I can synchronize the forked repo's wiki by merge upstream commands, however I don't know how to create pull requests if I updated the wiki and want to create a pull request to the upstream repository.

So my question is rt, I searched through internet and found [Bitbucket: Send a pull request via command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721730/bitbucket-send-a-pull-request-via-command-line) and https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/pullrequests+Resource#pullrequestsResource-POST%28create%29anewpullrequest

I don't know how to compose the jason file properly, so I wish to have a solution here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, there is no way to create a pull request for a wiki page, however, you could create a feature request in [Bitbucket's issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues).

Currently the only thing you can do is create a patch for the changes and create a new issue containing the patch. The repository owner can then apple the changes and merge it into the wiki repository.
A patch contains a list of all changes and is quite commen when you can't fork the repo and merge it back automatically (in Bitbucket and Github, you can do that for every repo very easily). [Here](https://ariejan.net/2009/10/26/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-git/) is a great tutorial if you want to learn more about it.