# How to submit pull request via CLI to Bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request

What is the simplest way to perform a git pull request via CLI. I am tired of going to Bitbucket the whole time to create a pull request manually. Which is quite simple indeed:

1. Pull requests tab
2. Create pull request
3. Select source and destiny branches (edit comments, reviewers, etc)
4. Confirm

Pretty simple. How can I achieve this behavior through cli?
Let's say, in my teams' repository, I want to perform a PR from `develop` to `master` branch.

I have been checking [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull) and it doesn't seem so obvious. It asks me to choose a starting commit and, in the previous steps I described, I don't even get the chance to choose which commit should the PR start from.

Comment: Have you read the bitbucket docs https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/making-a-pull-request? Seems to cover all your questions to me

Comment: Yes. "_Mary can create the pull request through her Bitbucket account by navigating to her forked repository and clicking the Pull request button in the top-right corner._". That's what I want to stop doing

Comment: Sorry... I was going to say there's [hub](https://hub.github.com/), but didn't see that you were talking about BitBucket. :-(  There's no built-in way to do this in Git (it doesn't know anything about GitHub, BitBucket, etc.), so the only way would be to have a wrapper.  I'm not sure if you're using BitBucket server, but if so, the [bitbucket server cli](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/bitbucket-server-cli) may work for you.

Comment: I tried to apply the changes in your question to my answer as well. Question is now more or less a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721730/bitbucket-send-a-pull-request-via-command-line or am I missing something?

Comment: have you solved it in the meantime?

Comment: I have pretty much been using the old fashion way, through the Bitbucket website

Answer (score 3):

You could use a command line tool like [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) on the [bitbucket rest api](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/). How to create a pull request with `HTTP POST` [is documented here](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/pullrequests#post).

Give it a try:

```
 curl \ 
 -X POST \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -u username:password \
  https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/repositories/account/reponame/pullrequests \
 -d @pullrequest.json
```

with file `pullrequest.json` containing

```
 { 
     "title": "Merge some branches", 
     "description": "stackoverflow example",
     "source": { 
         "branch": { 
            "name": "mybranchToMerge" 
          }, 
          "repository": { 
            "full_name": "account/reponame" 
          } 
     }, 
     "destination": { 
         "branch": { 
             "name": "master" 
          } 
      }, 
      "reviewers": [ { "username": "reviewerUsername" } ], 
      "close_source_branch": false 
}
```

For more options look here:

[Bitbucket: Send a pull request via command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721730/bitbucket-send-a-pull-request-via-command-line)

More about `git request-pull` can be found here:

[Difference between 'git request-pull' and 'pull request'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49423624)

Comment: He's talking about forking a public repo. This answer alos lacks details and clarity

Comment: The question asks how to open a pull request via the git CLI, pushing a branch upstream skips the process altogether.

Comment: Not what I want. I don't want to push directly to the `master`. I want to achieve that via pull-request. Cause I want to add reviewers that might approve or not my PR

Comment: So your question is how to do it with the bitbucket API?

Comment: @jschnasse It wasn't, I was checking git request-pull documentation, but if it is easier through API then I am fine with it. The question is in fact how to do it in the easiest way

Comment: You can do it with curl via the REST-API. E.g. create a PR with a POST like documented here: https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/4.9.1/bitbucket-rest.html#idp2046528

Comment: I repeat, your treating this as a private repo (i.e. one your company uses) not a open source public repo with contributors. He wants to **fork** not just push and pull some changes

Comment: [Just read this](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/making-a-pull-request) this is basically what the OP wants...

Comment: @Liam - No the OP wants to make a PR over command line. See question. Please revert downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the answer to your question is disappointing, as `Pull Requests` are not a native feature of git they are not supported through the CLI or any other standard `git` tool. Additionally there is no standard protocol for `Pull Requests` even outside of standard `git`. Each platform (`GitLab`, `GitHub` etc.) provides its own flavor of `Pull Requests`.

Since you question is about `Pull Requests` in general and not about `Pull Requests` on a specific provider the answer is that it cannot be done.

Comment: Thank you, that answers to it. But I will then edit the post to be Bitbucket specific.

Comment: @RenatoDamas Please open another question instead. Otherwise you'll invalidate all the answers here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bitbucket enterprise, i prepared a script to create/delete pull requests - https://github.com/psadi/bbcli.

It also handles adding of default reviewers automatically to your PR which is configured in your repo settings.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30868965)