# Workflow using git pull requests on self hosted git repo

Tags: git

I am trying to understand what a process that uses pull requests on a self-hosted git repo would look like (if it is even possible).

Say I have two branches, `feature` and `master`. A bunch of work is completed on the `feature` branch, and I want to submit a pull request for the changes to be reviewed before being merged into the `master` branch. As far as I understand it, the steps would be something like:

`git push feature` (developer pushes commits on `feature` branch to remote repo)

`git request-pull <start commit> feature <end commit>` developer creates the pull request. But I'm not entirely sure whether `<url>` should refer to `master` or `feature` branch?

Reviewer would then retrieve the pull request somehow, and if they are happy with it then they would merge the `feature` branch into `master` with `git merge feature`

Is such a workflow possible with self-hosted git? I haven't really used the likes of Github but I know they have a lot of GUI features to manage this sort of thing.

Summary of questions:

- what should `<url>` be in the git request-pull command?
- how does a reviewer receive the pull request?
- is there a way to view a history of pull requests?
- is there a way to have someone specific review the pull request?

Comment: "pull request" is not a feature of Git. It is a way of using it. Some hosting services, for example GitHub, provide it as a feature.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Here is the [git request-pull docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull). However it is not clear to me on how or whether it can be used in a self host git repo, or if it only exists for Github et al. I thought it would provide a nice way to show the changes being made for review at least, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard of that command. It is not related to GitHub. As far as I understand you would insert the URL of your self-hosted repository.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49423624/difference-between-git-request-pull-and-pull-request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As far as I understand it, the steps would be something like:
>
> `git push feature` (developer pushes commits on `feature` branch to remote repo)
>
> `git request-pull <start commit> feature<url> <end commit>` developer creates the pull request.
>
> Reviewer would then retrieve the pull request somehow, and if they are happy with it then they would merge the `feature` branch into `master` with `git merge feature`

These are exactly the steps for the pull request workflow.

The `git request-pull` command simply prints a nicely formatted summary of the changes from `<start commit>` to `<end commit>` which you can then send to a reviewer (for example, by email) to notify them. It doesn't send anything on its own.

You would insert the URL of your hosted Git repository as `<url>` so that the reviewer knows where they could find your commits. `<start commit>` would be the last commit before those which make up your changes. `<end commit>` would be the latest commit, i.e. `feature`.

You can experiment with the command locally by inserting `.` as `<url>` (i.e. the directory you're in).

---

> Summary of questions:
>
> - what should `<url>` be in the `git request-pull` command?

The URL of your hosted repository (can be a local directory name).
<sub>(It can be anything, the command will only warn you if there is no repository containing the mentioned commits at that location.)</sub>

> - how does a reviewer receive the pull request?

By sending them the output of the command.

> - is there a way to view a history of pull requests?

Not with `git request-pull`, you have to keep track of them yourself.

> - is there a way to have someone specific review the pull request?

By sending the output of `git request-pull` to them.