# Create a Pull Request on Bitbucket from the command line

Tags: git, command-line, bitbucket, pull-request

Is there a git command to create a [Pull Request](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/making-a-pull-request) directly on Bitbucket when pushing a Branch?

Or any other way to create Pull Request on Bitbucket directly from the command line or PHP

Comment: `git` doesn't have things like pull requests, so that's the wrong place to look for such a feature. However, there are git extensions that may help to integrate with other systems like Bitbucket's.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bitbucket: Send a pull request via command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721730/bitbucket-send-a-pull-request-via-command-line)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbitbucket%5D+command+line+pull+request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [BitBucket API](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/pullrequests) and POST the right command, [as in this thread](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Creating-a-pull-request-via-API/qaq-p/123913):

```
POST /rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/pull-requests
```

That is:

```
curl -u user:myPW -H "Content-Type: application/jso https://bitbucket.server.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/myProject/repos/myRepo/pull-requests -X POST --data @req.json
```

with data:

```
{"title":"test","description":"test","fromRef":{"id":"refs/heads/test-branch","repository":{"slug":"test-repo","name":null,"project":{"key":"myProject"}}},"toRef":{"id":"refs/heads/master","repository":{"slug":"myRepo","name":null,"project":{"key":"MyProj"}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Bitbucket pull requests API](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/pullrequests#post) via curl as it:

```
curl https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/my-username/my-repository/pullrequests \
-u my-username:my-password \
--request POST \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "title": "My Title",
    "source": {
        "branch": {
            "name": "staging"
        }
    }
}'
```