# How to create Pull request in Git Bash for a particular branch?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-bash

I want to create pull request from gitbash for a particular branch. I tried the following command but its not working.

[image]

Comment: What about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037928/can-you-issue-pull-requests-from-the-command-line-on-github)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a Pull Request on Bitbucket from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52089429/create-a-pull-request-on-bitbucket-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pull Requests are a feature of services such as GitHub and BitBucket that are built on top of Git. They are **not** part of Git itself. As you see, `git pull-request` is not a git command. In fact, there is no git command for creating a pull request. You will have to install a command line client from BitBucket in order to do this.