# How to create bitbucket pull request using gmail authentication

Tags: command-line-interface, bitbucket, pull-request

I have registered on bitbucket cloud using Gmail login, now I want to create a pull request from the command line. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by creating a personal access token for your bitbucket account: from the settings page of your bitbucket account, create a [bitbucket personal access token](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/personal-access-tokens-939515499.html). Then, as stated on that documentation page,

> For git operations, you can use your personal access token as a substitute for your password.

Now you can create a pull request two ways:

1. Use the bitbucket API directly (and a utility like cURL, or Python requests) - see [bitbucket API reference for pullrequest](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/pullrequests))
2. Use one of the command line tools mentioned in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15046966/463213).